# Doesn't update with pull refresh but rather repeats the old data

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a pull-refresh in quasar framework with the data coming from firebase firestore.

here is my method that tries to retrieve and refresh the data

```
retrieveAnnouncements() {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("announcement")
    .get()
    .then(snapShot => {
      snapShot.forEach(element => {
        const { TITLE, CONTENT, AUTHOR } = element.data();
        //add retrieved data in announcement
        this.announcements.push({
          key: element.id,
          TITLE,
          CONTENT,
          AUTHOR
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      alert("Failed to retrieve announcements");
      console.log(err);
    });
},
refresh(done) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.retrieveAnnouncements();
    done();
  }, 1000);
}
```

and here I tried to use the q-pull-refresh of quasar

```
<q-pull-to-refresh @refresh="refresh">
  <q-card
    class="q-ma-md"
    bordered
    v-for="announcement in announcements"
    :key="announcement.key"
  >
    <q-card-section>
      <div class="text-h6">{{announcement.TITLE}}</div>
      <div class="text-subtitle2">{{announcement.CONTENT}}</div>
    </q-card-section>
    <q-card-actions>
      <q-space />
      <q-btn color="green" @click="editAnnouncement(announcement.key)">Edit</q-btn>
      <q-btn color="red" @click="deleteAnnouncement(announcement.key)">Delete</q-btn>
    </q-card-actions>
  </q-card>
</q-pull-to-refresh>
```

but what I've accomplished it was just it repeat the data and doesn't get the latest data.

Here is the video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HOMURe23L_EvAVwTyBBOsnKbh94ZNwMh/view

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the array before pushing data to it

Add:

```
this.announcements = []; // clear the array
```

before the line:

```
this.announcements.push({
```